# Set default class of sorting icons on page load, then apply class on sorting icon click

Tags: css, angularjs

**Controller**

```
$scope.propertyName = "";
    $scope.reverse = 'none';
    $scope.sortBy = function (propertyName, val) {
        if ($scope.reverse === 'none') {
            $scope.reverse = false;
        }
        $scope.reverse = !val;
        $scope.propertyName = propertyName;
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{'sort': (reverse === 'none'), 'sort desc': reverse, 'sort asc': !reverse}" ng-click="sortBy('DivisionIndex',reverse)">
```

but on page load, `sort desc` class applies (reverse = true). i need to set class `sort` on page load and then change the value of reverse into boolean for apply css on sorting icons.

Comment: What is `"none"` there? Can't understand.

Comment: @SalmanLone try to understand clearly. As per your answer, you are adding sort class in all conditions. So, there is no need to keep it in ng-class. just keep as shown in my answer. And also observe clearly, I removed sort class and make them only asc and desc. Need to use better solution. Everyone wants that right

Comment: 1+ to your answer. I tried it before but it was not working at time. may be brackets around Boolean check was an issue or what. but now it is working as you said. Thank you for such discussion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple, If you want class onload Just mention it in `class` attribute and then change ng-class as shown

```
<div class="sort" ng-class="{'desc': (reverse===true), 'asc': (reverse===false)}" ng-click="sortBy('DivisionIndex',reverse)">
```

If you simply mention `reverse` at adding class using `ng-class`, the string `"none"` become true and also adds `"sort desc"` class. So, you must check with type and value as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not working. it applies the class on the basis of reverse value on page load.

Comment: That is what you need right. Page load you will have `sort` class and based on condition other class will get applied

Comment: No. i need to render the list in default way. no sorting is needed at start of page or you can say on page load. i only need to sort when user click on sorting icons and then apply the css on it.

Comment: But as per your question, adding class in my answer is correct. Tell me what do you want exactly, you can't sort the array with CSS right?

Comment: my sorting is working. now i need to add css class when user clicks on the sorting icons. for this, when i am trying the code in my question. the sorting css applies but the page is not sorted at that time. i do not need asc or desc class on page load.

Comment: @SalmanLone try to understand clearly. As per your answer, you are adding `sort` class in all conditions. So, there is no need to keep it in `ng-class`. just keep as shown in my answer. And also observe clearly, I removed `sort` class and make them only `asc` and `desc`. Need to use better solution. Everyone wants that right

Comment: There are 3 scenarios. first class="sort" which means default behaviour and no sorting. it is just a class name. second is class="sort asc" for acceding of list and third is class="sort desc" for descending . so i need sort class in anyway along with either no asc/desc or with each of them. I hope you got my point what i need and what is working for me.

Comment: `sort asc` or `sort desc` doesn't mean that is a single class. It means two classes. One is `sort` and the other is `asc/desc`. if you want to make it single class, use `sort-asc/sort-desc`. Now you know the difference between your answer and my answer

Comment: ng-class="{'desc': (reverse===true), 'asc': (reverse===false)}". This replace the complete value. i.e. if reverse is true, it set the 'desc' as a class and remove sorting from the value but i need 'sorting desc' if talking about particular case. so i need sorting in every case that is why i have added it repeatedly.

Comment: `ng-class` is to add or remove class in the condition. Not the other value of class attribute. i'm still doubt about you are not observed my/@SaiUnique answer clearly

Comment: You want `sort` class in every scenario. Then why you put it in `ng-class`. Write it in html itself(ie.` class="sort"`).

Comment: i tried putting it into html like class="sort" but ng-class removes the value and replace it all. then what left behind is asc or desc. @Mr_Perfect i already said you answer helped me but i made some slight changes in it to work it for me.

Comment: No, it does not remove the previous classes. You might doing something wrong.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9jb1heVum28mLqLxHzZm?p=preview @SalmanLone here observe `XYZ` class. You will get some clarification. Don't get trapped yourself by making things complex.

Answer (score -1):

You can do by using terenary operator:

```
<div class="sort" ng-class="{ reverse ? 'desc': 'asc'}" ng-click="sortBy('DivisionIndex',reverse)">
```

Comment: Using ternary operator or not is doesn't matter.

Comment: @SaiUnique you are right but my problem is to apply a default class on page load and apply sorting css on icons only when user click on sorting icons

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please revise the question and add some more details.